# Optimum usage of JIRA and Confluence

Tags: pm-software, jira, requirements

I'm working on recommendations for how to use JIRA and Confluence together for an Agile project. Based on experience teams use Confluence for requirements, linking to JIRA for the user stories themselves. Is this true for the majority of organisations that use both tools? I strongly suspect this is the case but wanted to post out the question to get thoughts and opinion.

To try and cram everything into JIRA would likely clog it up anyways. ;)

Comment: It depends highly on your business and its needs. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Consider this a business unit which owns a digital portfolio - i.e. they are all digital transformation projects which contain both IT and business workstreams. The organisation is on the road to agile, as mandated by the business and I.T, not I.T in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

In our company we use Confluence for discussions, concepts and documentation. In JIRA we make issues to create a backlog and plan sprints. Doing everything in JIRA won't work in my experience, as you may look over the details.

As a developer for Confluence and JIRA plugins I know our use cases and those of our customers. Most customers use both Confluence and JIRA and this totally makes sense as they work together great.

If you're doing software development, I would suggest to use more products of the Atlassian Familiy. This includes SCM "Bitbucket" and a build server "Bamboo".

Comment: This is precisely the configuration I've seen in a company I worked for as a contractor. In this case it was a publisher with a sophisticated digital platform. The entire company embraced Confluence and linked this with JIRA in the way you have described. It was pretty awesome tbh.

Comment: It is, as developer it is really cool, to also connect SCM and BuildServer. We even import README.md into Confluence from Bitbucket. Also we use Hipchat to get notifications from all systems. Advertising much...